# node js async callback issue

Tags: node.js, waterfall

i have a little bit issue with async waterfall as i want to call next function after a function in which loop is processing.The script is the part of async waterfall flow and previous functions are working just fine.The only thing here is that it has a for loop.The code is below.Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks

```
function(querySize,req)
{
console.log("in second function call :" +querySize);
var temp,title;
for(var counter = 0;counter <= querySize;counter++)
{
    websiteAddressArray[counter]  = req.query.address[counter];
    console.log("for  is : " +req.query.address[counter]);
    console.log("first line is : " +websiteAddressArray[counter]);
    console.log("second line  is : " +websiteAddressArray[counter]);
    request(websiteAddressArray[counter], function(err, resp, body)
    {
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log("title is : " +$('title').text());
        titleArray[counter] =  $('title').text();   
    });
  }
  var line="this is string";
  callback(null,line);
 },
 function(callback,line)
 {
  console.log("line is : " +line)
 },
```

Comment: where is your callback? and it's half of the code of waterfall , can you post your async.waterfall code?

Comment: @abdulbarik i have edited the code.My callback is the next function which takes the line and simply prints it

Comment: what's the console print `console.log("line is : " +line)`?

Comment: @abdulbarik it takes the line which is in previous function as parameter and print its

Answer (score 1):

Your `syntax` is not correct. always pass the `callback` last parameter in [async.waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall)

```
 function(querySize, req,callback) {
  console.log("in second function call :" + querySize);
  var temp, title;
  for (var counter = 0; counter <= querySize; counter++) {
    websiteAddressArray[counter] = req.query.address[counter];
    console.log("for  is : " + req.query.address[counter]);
    console.log("first line is : " + websiteAddressArray[counter]);
    console.log("second line  is : " + websiteAddressArray[counter]);
    request(websiteAddressArray[counter], function(err, resp, body) {
      $ = cheerio.load(body);
      console.log("title is : " + $('title').text());
      titleArray[counter] = $('title').text();
    });
  }
  var line = "this is string";
  callback(null, line);
},
function(callback, line) {
  console.log("line is : " + line)
},
```

Comment: bro i have changed the syntax has you have said but the error is still the same "callback is not defined"

Comment: Always try put put all information so that it's easy to get exact issue, here you have just mentioned one function of waterfall not complete